# Using HybridAuth with CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, hybridauthprovider

Did anybody tried to integrate [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) within CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [sample](http://bit.ly/wUVC3J) show how to integrate HybridAuth with CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: It might be useful to point to the github repository of this project (hybridigniter): https://github.com/andacata/HybridIgniter

Answer (score 4):

You should probably take a look at either [HybridIgniter](https://github.com/andacata/HybridIgniter) or the combination of [IonAuth and HybridAuth](https://github.com/mamprogr/CodeIgniter-IonAuth-HybridAuth)